# Density frequency height uncertainty in histogram

Tags: experimental-physics, statistics

I have a set of $ N=150 $ measurements of the acceleration of a falling mass:
$$
    X=\{x_i | i = 1,...,150\} 
$$
I have to plot this data in a histogram with fixed number of bins, let it be $N_{bin}$, and fixed bin width, let it be $\Delta_{bin}$. 
Hence my set of bins could be written as
$$
    bins=\{Xmin + i \Delta_{bin}| i =0,
\dots, N_{bin}\}
$$
Foreach $bin_k \in bins$, I calculate $N_k$ as the count of 
$x_j \in X | x_j \in bin_k$.
Now I have to calculate:
$$
    F_k = \frac{N_k}{N}
$$
And
$$
    f_k = \frac{F_k}{\Delta_{bin}} = \frac{N_k}{\frac{N}{\Delta_{bin}}} = \frac{N_k}{N\Delta_{bin}}
$$
which it is known as the frequency density of the k-th bin.

Here we go to the point. The assignment ask me to calculate the error on $f_k$, knowing that the error on $N_k$ is 
$$
    \Delta_{N_k} = \sqrt{Nk}
$$

I only have error on $N_k$ since $N$ and $\Delta_{bin}$ are parameters I decide by myself. 
The error on $f_k$ shall be:
$$
 \Delta_{f_k}= \sqrt{ (\frac{d f_k}{d N_k} \Delta_{N_k})^2 + \dots}
$$
I am not sure if it is correct to calculate such an error using the propagation error formula, because the only parameter affected by error is $N_k$, and this error is $\sqrt{N_k}$, but the assignment involves the utilisation of error propagation formula.

This is what I'm expected to draw:
[image: I need to plot data in a histogram like this]

Comment: There are no errors in the counts. There are uncertainties in the acceleration measurement. All the other statistical attempts at "errors" in the frequency counts are fallacious, especially since the histogramming you are doing is totally artificial. What one could do is find a parametric or maybe non-parametric *uncertainty of the mean* of the distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have measurements of the time it takes to fall, not the acceleration of a falling mass. (Hence the units: counts per second vs seconds).

If there are $N_i$ counts in a bin, your *estimate* of the uncertainly is $\sqrt{N_i}$. If you scale that by a parameter $\alpha$ to get a histogram value:

$$ y_i = \alpha N_i$$

and

$$ \Delta y_i = \alpha \sqrt{N_i}$$

whatever you use for $\alpha$. This is a very rudimentary form of error propagation, since it's a linear function.

From there you can fit it, using the $y_i$ and $\Delta y_i$ values to compute a chi-squared.

If the $N_i$ are small (you smallest $N_i$ appears to four), you can run into problems for several reasons:

Suppose the "true" rate in 2 bins is 3.5 (and the true fluctuations are $\sqrt{3.5}$), but one has 3 counts and one has 4 counts. A weighted average is biased low (3.42 vs 3.5) because the *estimated* uncertainties are so different (The "3" measurement gets more weight because $\sqrt 3 < \sqrt 4$).

Also, with so few counts, the results may depend on your choice of binning, hence the comment regarding other statistical methods.

The way to avoid these problems without doing a different analysis is to make $N$ bigger.

Comment: Ok that's more simple than I thought. In the image I've posted, there are times in the abscissa, I have accelerations and not times. It was just an example of the uncertainty to which I refer, however, thank you